# What will happen if I leave "updatePeriodMillis" field blank in Widget Info XML file?

Tags: android, appwidgetprovider

I don't want to update my widget periodically. If I just leave this field blank, will it create any problems or update it after some default time period ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set it to **0** or **remove the attribute** totally.